# how to catch an error like failed to open stream and Connection timed out

Tags: php, soap, error-handling, try-catch, soap-client

I got a code that interacts with a soap client that I enclose with a try catch statement. But it seems that the try catch statement could not catch the error as the script would fail. I would like the code to continue the execution even after the error.

The error is 
     [error] [php]SoapClient::SoapClient(): failed to open stream: Connection timed out

How to better handle the error without stopping the execution of the code?

Below is the code.

```
try{

   $client = new SoapClient($url, $config);

   $result = $client->RemoteMethod(
                array( "param1" =>$data1 
                "param2" => $data2
                "param3" => $data3
                )
            );

    $response = objectToArray($result); 

}catch(Exception $e){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the current namespace? Try changing the `catch` to:

```
}catch(\Exception $e){
```

(Note the backslash.)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer with the help of another question [Handle SOAP fatal error when there is a connection issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950981/handle-soap-fatal-error-when-there-is-a-connection-issue)

I used the error_reporting and trigger_error function.